# Why the function signature of thread constructor and bind in c++ is the same

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, bind

Recently, I am playing around with c++ multi-threading stuff, the signature of constructor of a thread is

thread (Fn&& fn, Args&&... args)

and the signature of c++ bind function is

bind (Fn&& fn, Args&&... args);

I don't think it is a coincident, but I cannot tell a concrete reason. Can anyone see the logic behind these two function?

Comment: They both receive a function to call and arguments to call it with. Why wouldn't they be the same?

Comment: They both happen to accept functions that will be called later. It is definitely coincidental.

Comment: I recently noticed that `std::sinf` and `std::cosf` have the same signature. I don't think it's a coincidence, can anyone see the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider what these things do:

Thread binds arguments to a function (all arguments of the function), and immediately starts a thread, where the bound function is executed.

Bind *binds* arguments to a function (not necessarily all of them), and returns a functor of lesser or equal arity that can be executed later.

So, the API of thread combines the binding of arguments, and the execution of the bound result in a new thread. Since the binding of arguments is an initial part of creating a thread, it should not be a great surprise, that the binding of arguments, and creation of a thread happen to have similar - even identical signatures. It is a consequence of the chosen approach for the API.

This was not the only option. Another design could have been to accept a nullary functor. A user would then have to explicitly bind arguments to create a nullary functor to create a thread with. The chosen approach of combining the binding and execution in new thread requires the user to write less boilerplate.

Comment: Not sure about that bit about the arity. A bind expression can be called with many arguments.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't claim that you couldn't call bind with many arguments. If you bind one argument to a ternary function, you get a binary functor. If you bind three arguments, you get a nullary functor. And so on. Each bound argument reduces the arity by one. Is there part of my answer that you find contradictory?

Comment: I'm not sure you can "get an n-ary functor" if you can call it with != n arguments... anyway, `bind` also has *placeholders* which allow you to construct functors of arbitrary "arity" (in your sense), so I think "lesser arity" is just not a general statement I'd make.

Comment: Yes, the number of placeholders is what determines the arity of the resulting functor (bind expression). Indeed, you can of course use all place holders, so "lesser arity" isn't strict. I clarified that now.

Comment: @KerrekSB I took a look at [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) and apparently, you can call the bind expression with more arguments than there are place holders for, and those extra arguments are discarded. Is this what you're referring to as an argument for the expression not having a lesser arity? I suppose that's correct then, but I'm not sure how to express my meaning while staying technically correct.

Comment: How about just "and returns a functor that can be called later"?

Answer (score 0):

The logic is as follows: one function constructs a threaded computation that calls a callable object perfect-forwarding arg values, while the other creates a partial function application, or section, or, in one case as a special overload, functional composition.